# Where is the returning Contract Monad in the handleError function of Contract Monad?

Tags: plutus, plutus-pioneer-program

The type of handleError function is

```
:: (e -> Contract w s e' a)-> Contract w s e a -> Contract w s e' a
```

It takes two arguments

- a function which takes error and returns a Contract monad `(Contract w s e' a)` without error
- Contract Monad with error

and returns a Contract Monad without error `(Contract w s e a)`. This is what I could understand. However when this is used in the following code

```
payContract = do
   pp <- endpoint @"pay"
   let tx = mustPayToPubKey (ppRecipient pp) $ lovelaceValueOf $ ppLovelace pp
   handleError (\err -> Contract.logInfo $ "caught error: " ++ unpack err) $ void $ submitTx tx
   payContract
```

In this function call `submitTx Tx` gives the Contract Monad with error and the lambda function `\err -> Contract.logInfo $ "caught error: " ++ unpack err` may be the first argument. What is happening to the returned Monad without error? and why void is used?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Definitions:**

`submitTx :: forall w s e. (HasWriteTx s, AsContractError e) => TxConstraints Void Void -> Contract w s e Tx`

`void :: Functor f => f a -> f ()`

`handleError :: (e -> Contract w s e' a)-> Contract w s e a -> Contract w s e' a`

**Explaination:**

`submitTx tx` is of type `Contract w s e Tx`, i.e. a Contract Monad with return type `Tx`.

`void` takes any Monad and maps it to a Monad with return type `()`. This is useful if you don't care for the returned value: `void $ submitTx tx :: Contract w s e ()`

`handleError` then takes the Monad and handles any errors with the specified error handler (`e -> Contract w s e' a`). However, it doesn't change the return type of the Contract Monad. In case there is no error on runtime the return value is just passed through.

`payContract` calls itself recursively on the last line of the do block in order to listen to the `pay`-endpoint indefinitely. Let's assume you'd leave out `handleError` and only use `void $ submitTx tx` your contract would crash on the first submission error.

If you wouldn't use `void`, your program would still be valid, but your compiler would output a warning, because you didn't use the return value of `submitTx tx`.

Answer (score 2):

> What is happening to the returned Monad?

All of this takes place within the `do` block. So, similar to the

```
<- endpoint @"pay"
```

the returned Monad is being abstracted away for you. The whole function is returning a `Contract`, so if it fails on either line, it will exit "early" and return the failed value. The reason it's not using the `<-` symbol is the answer to your second question:

> why void is used?

We don't need the contained value.

```
void :: Functor f => f a -> f ()
```

So, `void` for `Contract` converts `Contract w s e a` to `Contract w s e ()`.

---

You could also do this conversion by ignoring the output of a monad, as long as you still return the correct `a` for `Contract`, which in this case is `()`.

```
_ <- submit tx
return ()
```

is equivalent to

```
void $ submit tx
```

However, `void` is more explicit and fits better with the

```
handleError (\err -> Contract.logInfo $ "caught error: " ++ unpack err)
```

in your example.